# Unity Gradle build failed when version changed after adding google plugins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm a beginner developer in Unity and trying to build a game. But whenever I add a google plugin(either it is firebase, AdMob or play games services) and try to change my version number or name, grade build failed with tons of errors.

I think something in player settings and the files which google added conflicts. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you ever change your Unity version, you have to re-download and install the corresponding Android module for Unity.

Comment: I already tried that but still I can change the version once :( If I try one more time to change it, the same error appears.